# Serialize vector of boxed traits to JSON

Tags: json, serialization, rust

I am trying to serialize a collection of `struct`'s which may be of different types but implement a trait. The following does not compile in the playpen but shows what I am trying to do:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;

trait Account {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &String;
}

#[derive(RustcEncodable, RustcDecodable)]
struct Account1 {
    name: String,
}

impl Account1 {
    fn new() -> Account1 {
        Account1 { name: String::from("Account1") }
    }
}

impl Account for Account1 {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &String {
        &self.name
    }
}

#[derive(RustcEncodable, RustcDecodable)]
struct Account2 {
    name: String,
}

impl Account2 {
    fn new() -> Account2 {
        Account2 { name: String::from("Account2") }
    }
}

impl Account for Account2 {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &String {
        &self.name
    }
}

#[derive(RustcEncodable, RustcDecodable)]
struct Accounts {
    accounts: Vec<Box<Account>>
}

impl Accounts {
    fn new() -> Accounts {
        let accs: Vec<Box<Account>> = Vec::new();
        Accounts { accounts: accs }
    }

    fn add_account(&mut self, account: Box<Account>) {
        self.accounts.push(account);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut accounts = Accounts::new();
    let acc1 = Box::new(Account1::new());
    accounts.add_account(acc1);
    let acc2 = Box::new(Account2::new());
    accounts.add_account(acc2);
}
```

[Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=31fb1abfa9fab8311f3f&version=stable)

On my machine I am getting the following error:

```
error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `account::Account` [E0277]
```

I think the error is saying that for this to work the compiler needs to know the size of each `Box`-ed element at compile time. How can I solve this problem?

I think I am doing this how I would do it in Java/C++ but I should probably think in a different way in Rust. Please suggest if there is any better alternative to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you move away from the `struct`s + common `trait` setup and use an `enum`. This obviously doesn't allow users of your crate to add new account types, but even if it were allowed somehow, your deserialization code would never know about the new types and not be able to deserialize them. There certainly would be ways to "register" some kind of deserializers depending on certain tags, but as long as you have a fixed set of account types, an enum allows you to use the existing (de-)serialization framework.

First you create a general `Account` type that holds all fields that are common to accounts

```
#[derive(RustcEncodable, RustcDecodable)]
struct Account {
    name: String,
    kind: AccountType,
}
```

Then you create an enum that has variants of all accound types there are. If an account type needs extra fields, just add them to the appropriate enum variant.

```
#[derive(RustcEncodable, RustcDecodable)]
enum AccountType {
    Account1,
    Account2,
}
```

Your `Accounts` manager doesn't even require `Box`es anymore:

```
#[derive(RustcEncodable, RustcDecodable)]
struct Accounts {
    accounts: Vec<Account>
}
```

You can try out the entire thing in the [Playground](http://is.gd/C2ejtY) but make sure to use the `rustc_serialize` and not the hack I used in the Playground to make it run in the playground. All but the first two lines are 100% compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The automatically-generated implementations of the `Encodable` and `Decodable` traits wouldn't do the right thing; I'm not sure I've ever seen someone try to serialize a trait object before. There's no `struct` to reflect on to know what names and types to output for a trait.

To fix your problem, you can implement the traits yourself. Here's an example that just creates an array of the names:

```
impl Encodable for Accounts {
    fn encode<S: Encoder>(&self, s: &mut S) -> Result<(), S::Error> {
        s.emit_seq(self.accounts.len(), |s| {
            for (idx, a) in self.accounts.iter().enumerate() {
                try!(s.emit_seq_elt(idx, |s| {
                    s.emit_str(a.get_name())
                }))
            }

            Ok(())
        })
    }
}
```

However, I don't know how you would write a decoder — which concrete type will you choose to implement the trait?

---

For reference, here is the auto-generated implementation, found through the `--pretty expanded` option to `rustc`. I cleaned it up a bit for readability:

```
impl Decodable for Accounts {
    fn decode<D: Decoder>(arg: &mut D) -> Result<Accounts, D::Error> {
        arg.read_struct("Accounts", 1, |d| {
            let a = try!(d.read_struct_field("accounts", 0usize, Decodable::decode));
            Ok(Accounts { accounts: a })
        })
    }
}
```

The compiler error:

```
src/main.rs:118:66: 118:83 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Account` [E0277]
src/main.rs:118             let a = try!(d.read_struct_field("accounts", 0usize, Decodable::decode));
                                                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```